# R: Compiling issue

Tags: r, ubuntu

I want to compile the R source code on my own.
In order to this, I have installed all the required packages and two more with these commands

```
sudo apt-get build-dep r-recommended
sudo apt install libicu-dev gobjc-5
```

Then, I run the usual commands to configure with two additional options

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-ICU
```

Until now everything ok, but  when I tried to compile with the `make` command and at a certain point I got these error messages

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/Downloads/R-3.2.3/src/library/Recommended'
begin installing recommended package MASS
Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'MASS.ts' failed
make[2]: *** [MASS.ts] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/Downloads/R-3.2.3/src/library/Recommended'
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'recommended-packages' failed
make[1]: *** [recommended-packages] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/Downloads/R-3.2.3/src/library/Recommended'
Makefile:77: recipe for target 'stamp-recommended' failed
make: *** [stamp-recommended] Error 2
```

I have searched online but I haven't been able to figure it out what causes that error.

Thanks in advance.

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly:

- You probably need `apt-get build-dep r-base` to get build-dependencies, not `apt-get build-dep r-recommended`
- Your error is from also trying to build recommended packages *for which you need an additional download step* as explained in the documention
- So add `--without-recommended-packages` to the configure call.

Comment: The `build-dep r-recommended` it refers to `r-base` when it is executed and I thought it was fine.
For the recommended packages it is necessary to run `./tools/rsync-recommended` as stated in the documentation...I didn't see that thing! Thanks!